# Find all primary key and foreign key who use a colunm that need type change

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to change a column data type from int4 to varchar(30) and this column is primary and foreign key in several other tables.
So I'm trying to list all the pks and fks that use this column and after alter all this tables and constrains.

So I have 2 questions:

1) there is a smarter way to do this type change?

2) How can I list all this pks and fks one line for each?
(with the select below there is one line for each column in the constraint)

using postgres 10.10

```
select 
    tco.constraint_name,
    tco.constraint_type,
    kcu.table_schema,
    kcu.table_name,
    ccu.table_schema,
    ccu.table_name,
    ccu.column_name
from information_schema.table_constraints tco
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
     on kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
     and kcu.constraint_schema = tco.constraint_schema
     and kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON ccu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
where 
    ( tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' or  tco.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' )
    and 
    kcu.column_name='column_name'
```

Comment: Wow... Are you sure that you want to transform a pkey in a varchar type? The index treatment is definitly going to explode...

Comment: We know is not a good option in this perspective, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the misconception that can done by what you want to achieve, here is the code that is (I think) doing what you want on your '2)'.

Test structure :

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id int primary key);
create table test_2 (id int, id_1 int);
alter table test_2 add constraint pk_test_2 primary key (id, id_1);
alter table test_2 add constraint fk_test_2_test_1 foreign key (id_1) references test (id);
create table test_3 (id int primary key, id_2 int, id_1 int);
alter table test_3 add constraint fk_test_3_test_2 foreign key (id_2, id_1) references test_2 (id, id_1);
```

The query :

```
SELECT
    rel.relname as table_name
    , ccu.relname as ref_table_name
    , pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) as con_def                      
    , con.conname
    , col.attname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con                                   
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel                              
        ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp                          
        ON nsp.oid = connamespace                           
    left outer JOIN pg_class AS ccu 
        ON con.confrelid = ccu.oid
    JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(con.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(attnum, attposition) ON TRUE
    JOIN pg_attribute col ON (col.attrelid = rel.oid AND col.attnum = u.attnum)
WHERE nsp.nspname = 'public'
    and col.attname = 'id';
```

Or something like this :

```
select 
    tco.constraint_name,
    tco.constraint_type,
    kcu.table_schema,
    kcu.table_name,
    ccu.table_schema,
    ccu.table_name,
    string_agg(distinct ccu.column_name, '; ')
from information_schema.table_constraints tco
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
     on kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
     and kcu.constraint_schema = tco.constraint_schema
     and kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON ccu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name
where 
    ( tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' or  tco.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' )
    and tco.constraint_schema = 'public'
group by tco.constraint_name,
    tco.constraint_type,
    kcu.table_schema,
    kcu.table_name,
    ccu.table_schema,
    ccu.table_name;
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, the `pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid)` was really helpfull

Comment: Do you need any more help ?

Comment: In fact, will be nice if in your first select there is a filter by collumn name or if in the second one has the constraint definition.

Comment: do not forget to approve the answer ;)